# IoC with ASMX Like you can in WCF?

Tags: inversion-of-control, asmx

Can ASMX have an IOC like WCF?

Basically I want to be able to inject my dependencies into the ASMX web service. is this possible and if so how.

WCF way (somthing like this would be awesome)
http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/jimmy_bogard/archive/2008/07/29/integrating-structuremap-with-wcf.aspx

Comment: What's your reason for using ASMX, given that WCF has the feature you nead, and given that ASMX is now considered to be "legacy technology" by Microsoft.

Comment: Exellent question, I am looking into a POC, where WCF promotes clean code vs ASMX where its strongly coupled. I was seeing if ASMX can support IoC. From what i can see it does not, so I thought it would be a good question to ask incase someone else knows: if it can or cannot be done.

Comment: I think your better comparison is WCF, which is a current technology, vs. ASMX, which is a legacy technology. "Legacy technology" makes most other comparisons moot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `spring.net` have done this

http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/webservices.html